# Decrypt ruby DES-EDE3-CBC encrypted data in Python

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, openssl

I have a bunch of data which are encrypted in Ruby by following code

```
text = '12345678'
key = '6b4f0a29d4bba86add88be9d'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').encrypt
cipher.key = key
s = cipher.update(text) + cipher.final
encrypted_text = s.unpack('H*')[0].upcase
# => 3B223AA60F1921F34CBBBAC209ACDCE4
```

It can be decrypted in Ruby

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').decrypt
cipher.key = key
s = [encrypted_text].pack("H*").unpack("C*").pack("c*")
cipher.update(s) + cipher.final
# => 12345678
```

Now I have to decrypt the data in Python.
I wrote the encryption code as below:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key = '6b4f0a29d4bba86add88be9d'
iv = Random.new().read(DES3.block_size)
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
text = '12345678'.encode()
encrypted = cipher.encrypt(text)
encrypted_text = encrypted.hex()
print(encrypted_text)
# => f84f555b02e3ee24
```

As you can see, the encrypted data is quite different, at least is the length. So decryption part does not work.
How can I modify the Python code to compatible with Ruby?
Unfortunately, the data were available there by ruby application so I can only modify Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For compatibility with the Ruby code, the Python code lacks:

- the PKCS#7 padding
- a zero IV (i.e. an IV consisting of all 0x00 values). For Triple DES, the blocksize and therefore the IV is 8 bytes in size.

With this, the Python code has to be fixed as follows:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key = '6b4f0a29d4bba86add88be9d'
iv = b'\0' *  DES3.block_size                       # apply a zero IV
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
text = pad('12345678'.encode(), DES3.block_size)    # pad
encrypted = cipher.encrypt(text)
encrypted_text = encrypted.hex()
print(encrypted_text.upper()) # => 3B223AA60F1921F34CBBBAC209ACDCE4
```

With this change, the Python code provides the result of the Ruby code.
The corresponding decryption is:

```py
...
key = '6b4f0a29d4bba86add88be9d'
iv = b'\0' *  DES3.block_size     
cipher = DES3.new(key.encode(), DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
ciphertext = bytes.fromhex('3B223AA60F1921F34CBBBAC209ACDCE4')
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
decryptedUnpadded = unpad(decrypted, DES3.block_size)
print(decryptedUnpadded.decode('utf8')) # => 12345678
```

---

Note, however, that the code has vulnerabilities:

- The use of a static IV results in the reuse of key/IV pairs when applying a fixed key, which is a more or less severe vulnerability depending on the mode. To avoid this, a common approach is to generate a random IV for each encryption. This IV is not secret and is given to the encrypting side along with the ciphertext (generally concatenated).
- Actually, the key should be a random byte sequence and not a string, because of the usually lower entropy. If the key material is a string, a key derivation function (at least PBKDF2) should be applied in conjunction with a random, not secret salt.
- CBC is not authenticated encryption. Authenticated encryption guarantees authenticity/integrity in addition to confidentiality.
- Triple DES is deprecated, the current standard is AES.